# Changing column collation - Unique Index duplicated

Tags: sql-server, ssms, collation

Recently I had issues with string comparison including emojis with my SQL Server database and thus I changed the whole databases's collation from SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS.

I understand all the existing tables/columns still remains the old collation so I have to change them manually. While changing one of the tables with a complex Primary Key: `[KeyA (int), KeyB (nvarchar(100))]`, I encounter this error:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MyTable' and the index name 'PK_MyTable'. The duplicate key value is (7792, #صلح‌گرا).

I tried to do a `SELECT` with `count(*)` group by the 2 keys but did not seem to find any legit duplicates. What should I do to resolve the above?

Edited:

The following query yields no result since I have already got the PK pair in place before changing the collation:

```
SELECT KEYA, KEYB, COUNT(*)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY KEYA, KEYB
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Edited (2):

Thanks for everyone's inputs. Now I see duplicates by querying with the new collation. Here is an example of the results. Seems `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` does not handle Persian characters (or maybe RTL in general) well. But the issue here is that this field could hold many different kinds of languages, e.g. English, French, German, Chinese, Japanese, etc. All sorts of accents and JFK and RTL languages could exist. Is there any collation I should use that handles these well?
[image: Query Result with destination collation specified]

Comment: Changing from SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS doesn't change the column contents, they're both Windows Code Page 1252. This table did not previously have a PK constraint on (KeyID, KeyB), correct? So you need to fix the data before you can put a unique constraint on it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This is currently a PK pair already before changing the collation

Comment: Your test query is using the old/existing collation. You need to modify that to collate `KEYA` & `KEYB` to the new collation to check whether there are duplicates or not.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the OP after correcting the query.

Answer (score 1):

As Dale as mention, you are using your old collation in that `group by` query.

Use `COLLATE` to change to the new collation on your query and check for duplicates.

```
SELECT KEYA COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, 
       KEYB COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY KEYA COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, 
         KEYB COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the OP after correcting the query.